# Taking an iAd across multiple screens

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, iad

I'm sure there's a simple answer to this but it's beginning to annoy me now!

I have an iAd integrated into my app which appears and works on the screen I've implemented it in. The app uses a NavigationController to move between multiple screens, but the iAd is only on one of them. After moving from start to finish through my app several times I get a message appear in GDB saying:

`Too many active banners (11). Creation of new banners will be throttled.`

The app then crashes.

I have tried looking through the Apple documentation and searched on Google and can't see a solution to the problem.

If anyone has any idea how I can resolve the issue it would definitely stop me from going mad! Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you're not removing your iAds when views hide. I suggest doing the creation in `viewWillAppeaer` and removing ads in the `viewDidDisappear` method. Like this, you'l only end up with as many banners as you create in the visible view. It sounds like you're using the `viewdidLoad`/`viewWillUnload` pair instead.

Comment: I have moved the creation and deallocation code to viewWillAppear and viewDidDisappear and it no longer displays the error or crashes! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great! A quick note of explanation: The views that get pushed and popped from the screen are retained in memory, which is why the iAds are not simply being removed when the views become invisible. Making the change that you did, however, solves the problem.

Comment: @Moshe when I try to remove the AdBannerView in my viewWillDisappear the AdBannerView still loads in my next view controller. Can you explain?

Comment: @ThisDarkTao Can you share the code you used to make the AdBannerView go away?

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to create the ADBannerView in a fixed location across all screens. It's a little bit harder than the above method, but it looks nice. For example, if you have a tab bar controller application, you can do the following in your app delegate:

```
    [self.myTabBarController.view addSubview:self.myAdView];
```

It can get a little bit tricky to place other views underneath the ad.