# iAd "Too many active banners, Creation of new banners will be throttled." warning

Tags: iphone, iad

I have ADBannerView created and deleted on ViewWillAppear and ViewWillDisappear separately, even though, after switching to another view that doesn't have ADBannerView created, I am still seeing tons of the warning. What does it mean? How can I fix it?

```
"Too many active banners, Creation of new banners will be throttled."
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    adView = [[AdBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:GCResctMake(0,0,320,50)];
    adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50];
    adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50;
    adView.delegate=self;
    bannerIsVisible=NO;
    adView.hidden = YES;
    [adContainerView addSubview:adView];
    [adView release];
}
```

Comment: Try this link if it doesn't help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030452/taking-an-iad-across-multiple-screens