# How to make iAd to be viewed globally in my app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, adbannerview

I am developing an application where i have to show iAds in all the pages of my application..
I created a subclass of UIView where i am initializing the the ADBannerView and its delegate methods.

But now if I add it in window in AppDelegate class it is giving me following error at run time 
"ADBannerView must be part of a view hierarchy managed by a UIViewController"..

I think this mean that I can use ADBanner only in UIViewController's subclass file??

if so then how can I make it global??

Thanks in Advance
Shreya

Comment: Also take a look at accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422177/is-it-a-good-practice-to-delete-the-adbannerview-on-viewwilldisappear-and-add-it/9422360#9422360

Comment: Hey @user1036925 : if u got the answer from below post . kindly accept it. :)

Comment: @shreya: make it on window on appdelegate then its possible .....!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In AppDelegate class you can make a shared object.

```
- (ADBannerView *) sharedBannerView
{
    if (_sharedBannerView == nil)
    {
        Class classAdBannerView = NSClassFromString(@"ADBannerView");

        if (classAdBannerView != nil)
        {
            _sharedBannerView = [[classAdBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 50)];

            // pre 4.2 doesn't have the new AdBannerSize constants. 
            if (&ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait != NULL)
            {
                [_sharedBannerView setRequiredContentSizeIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObjects:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait, ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape, nil]];            
            }
            else
            {  
                [_sharedBannerView setRequiredContentSizeIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObjects:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50, ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32, nil]];            
            }
        }   
    }

    ((ADBannerView *)_sharedBannerView).backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    return _sharedBannerView;
}
```

And add this shared object to the view wherever you need to display iAds.
Hope you get it.

Comment: @user1036925: also take a look at this technical note from Apple: [TN2286: Implementing a Shared iAd Banner](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2286/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011212)